# Javascript DOM Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, validation, dom

Goodmorning everyone!
I write because I have this problem and I would like to improve my knowledge of codeigniter and javascript . I have a form like this:

```html
<?php echo form_open('welcome/listalocali', 'class = "form-home"', 'name = "formprincipale"'); 
             $indirizzo = array(
         'type'  => 'text',
         'name'  => 'indirizzo',
         'id'    => 'indirizzo',
         'placeholder' => 'Es. Via Farini 7, Parma',
         'class' => 'hiddenemail'
    );
    echo form_input($indirizzo);
?>
```

Vorrei operare con javascript sul contenuto inserito in input dall'utente, ad esempio inserendo un bottone che, quando premuto, mostri su un alert il contenuto del form. Ho pensato quindi ad una cosa di questo tipo:

```js
x = document.formprincipale.indirizzo.value();
alert(x);
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me by explaining how I have to do to operate on a written form in codeigniter with javascript ? In particular, how can I tell it to operate on the value of a particular input to a form? With normal html input I've always used the DOM. But it seems not work , and seemed at the input with that name !

Comment: If you could translate that part in the middle that would be swell hahahah

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that your problem has nothing to do with codeigniter, i strongly suggest that you use a library like jQuery because it helps so much to handle the dom - it really makes your coding life much easier

---

but the answer your are looking for is

```
x = document.getElementById("indirizzo").value;
alert(x);
```